# Using multiple condition for a DECODE

Tags: java, sql, oracle, maven, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have this sentence to decode in sql : if A AND B are not empty then return me this ID

How can i do it with the DECODE function?

Thanks

I did not found anything regarding the use of two different variables in a DECODE in sql

Comment: Use CASE intead of DECODE function. DECODE function is Oracle specific while CASE is the ISO SQL Standard and can have different predicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sample table; only `ID = 1` satisfies conditions you specified:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID A B
---------- - -
         1 x y   --> A and B are both NOT NULL, so ID = 1 should be returned
         2   z
         3 w
```

Can you do it with `decode`? Sure, but it is really *ugly* and difficult to write, read (understand) and maintain.

```
SQL> select id
  2  from test
  3  where 1 = decode(a, null, 0,
  4                            decode(b, null, 0, 1)
  5                  );

        ID
----------
         1
```

As commented, `case` expression is really *nice*, easy to write, read (understand) and maintain. I suggest you use it.

```
SQL> select id
  2  from test
  3  where 1 = case when a is not null and b is not null then 1
  4                 else 0
  5            end;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```